# Getting a boolean value from a parse object and performing a if/else statement on it in Xcode 7, Swift 2

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2, xcode7, pfquery

The title says it all. I have read through the Parse docs and it is just going right over my "new to coding" brain. How do I get a parse Boolean object, which i already have created, and perform a if/else statement on based on whether it is true or not?

Thank you

Comment: You should try a bit harder, come up with some code and come back again if it doesn't work. This way we can understand and explain to you what you need instead of just giving you a snipped of code you won't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use obj-c, not Swift, so I can't help you with syntax, but in iOS, you need to store/retrieve parse booleans as NSNumbers. So storing a boolean:

```
[myPFObject setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:myBool] forKey:@"myKey"];
```

for retrieving that object and using it as an if/else condition:

```
NSNumber *boolNumber = [myPFObject objectForKey:@"myKey"];
bool myBool = boolNumber.boolValue;
if( myBool )
...
```

Obviously, being able to do so depends on having properly saved / fetched your object from parse, which throws a lot of people off because it's synchronous, as in multi threaded.  Say you call `fetch` on your object, then immediately try to access that bool value. You won't be able to, because the fetch happens on a separate thread, and your main thread immediately goes to the next line you try to access it. You need to be using the fetch/saveInBackgroundWithBlock methods of PFObjects, and doing whatever you need to do with the values inside of the callback, rather than outside.

Comment: The latest version of the Parse SDK handles the integer/boolean conversion for you. You can use the swift boolean values as you normally would and everything will work as expected

Comment: @Russell Oh, this is news to me. That's awesome, because I always thought the whole NSNumber conversion looked gross in my code.

Comment: Absolutely and I whole-heartedly agree. I had the NSNumber conversions for a good chunk of time while working on a project and felt relieved to go back and refactor the code to be normal booleans :)